# Drawing Polygons in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv, image-processing, vector

What am I doing wrong here?

```
vector <vector<Point> > contourElement;

for (int counter = 0; counter < contours -> size (); counter ++)
{   
    contourElement.push_back (contours -> at (counter));

    const Point *elementPoints [1] = {contourElement.at (0)};
    int numberOfPoints [] = {contourElement.at (0).size ()};

    fillPoly (contourMask, elementPoints, numberOfPoints, 1, Scalar (0, 0, 0), 8);
```

I keep getting an error on the const Point part. The compiler says

```
error: cannot convert 'std::vector<cv::Point_<int>, std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > >' to 'const cv::Point*' in initialization
```

What am I doing wrong? (PS: Obviously ignore the missing bracket at the end of the for loop due to this being only part of my code)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let's analyse the offending line:

```
const Point *elementPoints [1] = { contourElement.at(0) };
```

You declared `contourElement` as `vector <vector<Point> >`, which means that `contourElement.at(0)` returns a `vector<Point>` and not a `const cv::Point*`. So that's the first error.

In the end, you need to do something like:

```
vector<Point> tmp = contourElement.at(0);
const Point* elementPoints[1] = { &tmp[0] };
int numberOfPoints = (int)tmp.size();
```

Later, call it as:

```
fillPoly (contourMask, elementPoints, &numberOfPoints, 1, Scalar (0, 0, 0), 8);
```

Comment: Thanks. However, on the line that states "const Point* elementPoints [1] = {tmp [0]};" I get the error saying " error: cannot convert 'cv::Point_<int>' to 'const cv::Point*' in initialization". Any idea why?

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to add an `&`. Updated the answer, please test it now.

Comment: Thanks. It compiles properly, but I have a question. Aren't you just pointing to one singular point? Don't you need to pass in all the points to draw the whole polygon?

Comment: You are pointing to the very first element of the vector, however `numberOfPoints` defines how many elements there are after that. ;)

Comment: Say, if I have 4 coordinates,(x1,y1), (x2,y2), (x3,y3) and (x4,y4)

How can I write this in the form of vector.? 

Please help.!!

Comment: @karlphillip- I am masking image using fillPoly.But it is givrng me mask for point(0,0) also.which is not required.Any idea why i am getting this?

Answer (score 26):

Just for the record (and because the opencv docu is very sparse here) a more reduced snippet using the c++ API:

```
  std::vector<cv::Point> fillContSingle;
  [...]
  //add all points of the contour to the vector
  fillContSingle.push_back(cv::Point(x_coord,y_coord));
  [...]

  std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > fillContAll;
  //fill the single contour 
  //(one could add multiple other similar contours to the vector)
  fillContAll.push_back(fillContSingle);
  cv::fillPoly( image, fillContAll, cv::Scalar(128));
```

Comment: Afaik this c++ call of fillPoly isnt documented anywhere, but it's the very easiest and most intuitive way to draw filled polygons!

Comment: Double >> in nested std::vectors does not work for GCC. I tried to add a space to the answer but it requires minimum 6 characters per edit.

Comment: @ lahjaton_j; Thxs, I added a blank

Comment: Nice! I was wondering why there wasn't any documentation regarding this way of doing it.
Also, in this single contour case, you can wrap it in the call:
`fillPoly(image, vector<vector<Point>>{fillContSingle}, color)`

Answer (score 3):

contourElement is vector of `vector<Point>` and not Point :) 
so instead of:

```
const Point *elementPoints
```

put

```
const vector<Point> *elementPoints
```

Comment: Thank You. But for the function, the argument has to be a const Point not a const vector of points.

Answer (score 1):

Some people may arrive here due to an apparently bug in the samples/cpp/create_mask.cpp from the OpenCV. This way, considering the above explained I edited the "if (event == EVENT_RBUTTONUP)" branch para to:

```
    ...
    mask = Mat::zeros(src.size(), CV_8UC1);
    vector<Point> tmp = pts;
    const Point* elementPoints[1] = { &tmp[0] };        
    
    int npts = (int) pts.size();        
    
    cout << "elementsPoints=" << elementPoints << endl;

    fillPoly(mask, elementPoints, &npts, 1, Scalar(255, 255, 255), 8);     
    bitwise_and(src, src, final, mask);
    ...
```

Hope it may help someone.